# Type of expression consisting only of a variable identifier

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) says:

> An identifier that names a variable, a function, specialization of a concept, (since C++20) or an enumerator can be used as an expression. The result of an expression consisting of just the identifier is the entity named by the identifier. [...] The type of the expression is determined as follows:
>
> [...]
>     Otherwise, the **type of the expression is the same as the type of the entity named**.

Isn't it a bug? If the entity is a reference, like:

```
int &a = ...
```

Then `a`'s type as an entity is `int &`, but `a`'s type as an expression is only `int`, isn't it? An expression's type is [never a reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> [...] Each expression has some non-reference type

Bonus question: does it matter, whether `a`'s type (as an expression) is `int` or `int &`? If yes, where does it make a difference?

---

Note: the same wording is used at [decltype](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype):

> If the argument is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access expression, then decltype yields the **type of the entity named by this expression**.

But clearly, `decltype(a)` is `int &`.

Answer (score 1):

This is what standard (draft) says:

> [expr.type] Expressions / Type
>
> If an expression initially has the type “reference to T”, the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. ...

So, clearly an expression can have a reference type - initially, before adjustment for type analysis.

> "Each expression has some non-reference type" is not true?

Depends on how you interpret it. An expression can have a non-reference type (initially), but all expressions have some non-reference type (after adjustment) that is used for type analysis.

> [expr.prim.id.unqual] Expressions / Unqualified names
>
> The result is the entity denoted by the identifier. ... If the entity is a template parameter object for a template parameter of type T ... [does not apply] ... Otherwise, the type of the expression is the type of the result. [Note: The type
>   will be adjusted as described in 7.2.2 if it is cv-qualified or is a reference type. — end note] ... [Example:
>
> ```
> void f() {
>     float x, &r = x;
>     [=] {
>         decltype(x) y1;        // y1 has type float
>         decltype((x)) y2 = y1; // y2 has type float const& because this lambda
>                                // is not mutable and x is an lvalue
>         decltype(r) r1 = y1;   // r1 has type float&
>         decltype((r)) r2 = y2; // r2 has type float const&
>
>     };
> }
> ```
>
> — end example]

---

> Decltype specifiers [dcl.type.decltype]
>
> ... if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or ..., decltype(e) is the type of the entity named by e.

Comment: So, in this case, the "Each expression has some non-reference type" is not true?

Comment: @geza Depends on how you interpret it. An expression can have a non-reference type, but all expressions have some non-reference type (after adjustment) that can be used for type analysis.

Comment: So, basically, `a`'s type (as an expression) is `int &`, but anything we do with it (further analysis?), it becomes `int`? Why isn't its type `int` in the first place? Does this matter at all? For example, no matter which is true, both `decltype(a)` and `decltype((a))` will be `int &`.

Comment: @geza if there wasn't an initial reference type, then you couldn't make rules for whether the expression is an lvalue or xvalue (which can depend on the type of the reference - not in case of id-expression though).

Comment: Hmm. `int &&a = ...`. Here, `a` is an rvalue reference, yet `a` is an lvalue. So I'm not sure that's the reason for this.

Comment: @geza yes, I meant that in general. In particular case of id-expression, that doesn't matter. I suppose that the type of an id-expression is specified like this so that `decltype` works the way it does, which I suppose is what the committee desired.

Comment: But `decltype(a)` has a special rule if `a` is a variable, so it doesn't consider `a`'s type as an expression. So considering `decltype`, it doesn't matter what `a`'s type is as an expression (because it returns the entity's type, not the expression's type).

Comment: @eerorika _if there wasn't an initial reference type, then you couldn't make rules for whether the expression is an lvalue or xvalue_ Nonsense.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Feel free to rewrite the rules so that an id expression of reference variable is initially a non-reference type, if you disagree.

Comment: @geza _`a`'s type (as an expression) is `int &`, but anything we do with it (further analysis?)_ Reasoning about `a`'s type, you are doing analysis. And prior to **any** analysis you have to drop the reference part. So, `a`'s type (as an expression) is `int`.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: so, "Otherwise, the type of the expression is the same as the type of the entity named" is indeed a bug, isn't it? Type of entity is a reference type (`int &`), but the type of the expression isn't (`int`, as you just said).

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't it a bug?

No. The type of `a` is `int`. Yeah true that this is only before the type adjustment, but since that *always* happens, it makes no sense to talk about expressions having reference type, since the reference disappears immediately.

> does it matter, whether `a`'s type (as an expression) is `int` or `int &`? If yes, where does it make a difference?

This is basically asking why we need value categories at all. Basically it would break move semantics because of rvalue references that are sometimes xvalues and sometimes lvalues.

Comment: cppreference: "type of the entity named." vs you: "An entity doesn't have a type.". Someone is incorrect. "The type of a is int". Do you mean `a` as a variable, or `a` as an expression? Didn't you want to write `int &`? It would make more sense to me.

Comment: @geza I mean the expression. Well true, entities can be things like namespaces that obviously don't have a type. you're right